# Доступ к файловой системе wimax-карты, варианты пароля

Tags: asus, vxworks, wimax, пароль

Не могу получить доступ к файловой системе wimax карты роутера ASUS WMVN25E2+ (YOTA).ФайлСистема - TFFS.  Через последовательный порт захожу без пароля, но необходимо разбирать аппарат и подключаться напрямую к контактам UART, при подключении через телнет необходимо предварительно включить режим моста и подключить карту, далее можно зайти по адресу 192.168.1.254 Но дальше система не пускает - появляется приглашение ASUS WIMAX и login/password. Стандартные пароли admin/admin не подходят (хотя по адресу 1.1 проходит без проблем). Через несколько секунд приглашение обновляется, через 60 - отключается. Вопрос - какие могут быть стандартные варианты паролей в этой ситуации, возможно кто-то сталкивался. Операционная система vxWorks

Comment: А нет ли возможности сначала зайти через последовательный порт, затем задать имя и пароль пользователя и потом входить через telnet по ним?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что вроде бы имя и пароль пользователя прописаны в бутлоадере стандартные. Я их вижу, когда захожу через последовательный порт. Но через телнет - никак.

Comment: Пока ничего не получается - пароль, вероятно, генерится на основе MAC адреса устройства, через последовательный порт в настройках, найдена команда установки логин/пароля (пароль указан как опция), но при входе через телнет все равно не пускает и сбрасывает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать bruteforce для telnet.

Ну и естественно я предлагаю это делать только на устройствах принадлежащих вам ;) Также не рекомендую в сети распространять пароль как его узнаете, я думаю вы наверняка слышали про дело Sony и Geohot.

Comment: @Сергей Спасибо, естественно я работаю с устройством, принадлежащим мне. Речь идет о настройках скрипта для wimax карты. Подключение последовательного порта - это необходимость разбирать устройство. Поэтому хотелось получить возможность подключаться через telnet.